# Filter search in Wikidata API

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to get filtered data from the [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbsearchentities), currently I can do a general search using this API, but now there have been specific cases where I have to filter this information, for example, I need to get a list of only authors to get the [Q identifier](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q43649390) and although I also reviewed the [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/) this is too heavy to bring all the items, I used a SPARQL query and did a test and to get less than 3000 results it took 26 seconds, this is too much for a search service.

This is the query I use to get the authors.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?author ?authorLabel WITH {
  SELECT ?item ?author WHERE {
    ?item wdt:P50 ?author.
  } LIMIT 100000
} AS %FOO {
  INCLUDE %FOO
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

I also need to search by categories but it has not been possible for me to filter the searches in any way, does anyone know a way to do it?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. The query as is gets you (in theory) all works and their respective authors. That's a few (hundred) million, which is why it times out.

Comment: I am trying to develop an advanced search using Wikidata, I need to be able to search for work and filter them by authors, but first I must be able to obtain a list of authors, unfortunately when trying to obtain the list and due to the type of SPARQL queries they return time out.